# How to call a function after Angular.js has routed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have done some routing using sammy and handlebars for rendering.
With sammy i could do this:
 `this.get('#/gallery', function(){    //sammy is defined and works
        var container = 'container';

        renderHandlebars(templates.gallery)    //this compiles my Handlebars 
        gallery(4);
    })`

In this way when i could call gallery(4); and be sure that the rendering is already done. So i could select DOM elements after. I decided to use Angular now but i have problems with it.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/home'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .when('/gallery', {
        templateUrl: 'views/gallery.html',
        controller: 'GalleryController'        
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

What i want is to call gallery(4) in the same way. But if i make it in the controller error come out.
What i ask is how to call it after the rendering is done. So I can select DOM element that were created with Angular.

Comment: Use directives, assures that element exists when code is run

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ng-Init directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) inside your `gallery.html`. Like this you can call a function from your `GalleryController` to use the get function.

Html code:

```
  <div ng-init="GalleryController.someFunction()">
     <!--more code-->
  </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
angular.module('initExample', [])
    .controller('GalleryController', function() {
       this.someFunction = function(){
         //use your get method here
       }
    });
```